# Is it possible to "tune" a trained model in one population so it can be used for a different population (i.e., by swapping variables)?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, model, validation, predictor

Say, I have trained a model to classify patients into cardiovascular disease (CVD) and non-CVD. The model building process is as follows:

- There is a gold standard to compare the model with. The trained model attempts to find the relevant predictors from administrative data (such as hospital and physician visit record). The gold standard is a survey that asks if patient has been diagnosed with CVD.
- From the admin data, 40 variables are derived as candidate predictors
- Model selection is done via multivariable logistic regression. And we find that 2 final variables are significantly related to CVD status, and were included as the variables in the final model. "Var1=Number of Hospitalization>3" is a dichotomous variable, i.e., if an individual has 2 hospitalization, he will be "0", if he has 7, he will be "1".

Y = -1.0 + 2.3(Var1=Number of Hospitalization>3) + 3.4(Var2=Number of physician visits>5)

- If Y(or the predicted probability) is greater than 0.5, the individual will be classified as CVD patient, otherwise non-CVD patient.

Now let's say this trained model is done in the Canadian population, and we want to apply it to the US population. And we know that the Hospitalization>3 and Physician visits>5 are not applicable to US population, where the vast majority of CVD patients have >7 hospitalizations and >10 physician visits.

Is there a way I can "tune" the trained model trained in a different population based on the distribution of the related variable in a different population?

One way to apply is to swap the variable cut off, into:

Y = -1.0 + 2.3(Var1=Number of Hospitalization>7) + 3.4(Var2=Number of physician visits>10)

Intuitively, this seems flawed since the parameters resulted from the trained model originally are specifically for Canadian population and for specific variables tested.

If so, are there any other feasible way to tune the model in an acceptable fashion, without gold standard in the new population and without conducting a full validation/model building study in the new population?